# How to solve "Cannot connect to server" message with wireless app distribution on iPhone iOS 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I found the pre-release docs for this at https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html (Developer account required)

and some more at: http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/

I'm running into issues when I click on the link to the .plist file

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.server.edu/iphone/calcs.plist">Install My App over the air</a>
```

-- the iOS4 device reports back:

Cannot connect to www.server.edu

Server names intentionally obscured

Obviously the device can connect to the server otherwise i wouldn't be able to see the page that has the link...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the SSL certificate valid? If it uses a self-signed certificate, or is invalid in some way (e.g. expired) then you'll get this error.

Comment: Hi , I am also getting same error like cannot connect to server .But this ipa file can be downloaded through dropbox. I am using Xcode 6.1.1 .Please help me out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run into this, but the first place I'd look is the web server access logs at www.server.edu, to see if a) the request is getting to the server, and b) it's returning an error. I'd bet that the server doesn't like something about the HTTP request coming from the device. Missing cookie? Authentication required? Expecting a particular "Accept" header?

Comment: I assumed that the authN/authZ credentials that were used to view the link to the website would also be available to whatever process is handling the installation, so I put the .ica file behind our auth... That was the problem. Now that I've moved it to a noauth space on our webserver, it's working great. Now, all I need to do is figure out how to prevent my users from creating their own .plist file and pointing to the 'public' .ica file... sigh.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want to avoid making the .ica publicly accessible. Could you put it on a private network, so the device would have to be on your secure wifi network to install?

Comment: @ChrisBrandt Oh man, I've been trying to solve this for hours - my private site was secured with forms authentication, and the (now ipa) app files were secured as well. Making them bypass auth made it work perfect, but unfortunately I'm in the same boat as you - I don't want my app files to by publicly available.

Comment: It seems that the download process is occurring AFTER it switches context to 'download / install' mode -- at this point, springboard (or whatever process is actively running) no longer has authenticated access to the server - so really, Christopher Pickslay's suggestion is really the only option.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because the SSL certificate had expired. Make sure you add that to the list of things to check. Once I renewed that it started working again.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem. It turns out there is a typo in the plist file.
Acutally, you don't need to create this plist file.
If you are using XCode to distribute, it will generate the right plist file with the ipa file.
Follow the following steps:
1. Sign your app with the enterprise distribution certificate.
2. Once you create the archive, go to Organizer, select the archive and click Distribute.
3.select "Save for Enterpise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" and click next.
4. Make sure you select the right code signing identity, the same certificate for in house distribution and click next.
5. When prompted for save, check "Save for Enterprise Distribution". It will ask for more information.
6. Application URL must be the url pointing to your ipa file when deployed in your app distribution server. You will need to have another two image files (required as 512*512 and 57*57).
7. When clicked save, plist file and ipa file will be created in the folder you chooose.

Official Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Manifest plist typo causes the mis-message of cannot contact server. I generate mine dynamically (find the latest build) and it had something in the generated characters that the iOS device did not like.

Answer (score 0):

Check authentication on your server on this page and plist file request.
Because cookies of your browser do not send them to itunes on device. 
Your plist file must be available without auth.

Comment: And if you generate plist programatically on server be sure what content-type = application/xml

Comment: Your plist doesn't have to be open to the public. Otherwise any distribution site like Testflight would have all their apps open to the public. Our internal system depends on cookie auth and it works just fine.

Comment: May be your system works because you are using ssl auth. But in my personal internal system I am not use ssl and problem was in auth